# How to post values of each item in model from view to controller as a List or Array?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

[example of view priority list of orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6jSx.png)
i have a orders model, i need the user to arrange orders in order of priority by numbers.
for each order a different number of priority and post to the controller the id of the order and the priority number that he selected for the order.
post it to the controller as a list/array of pairs (id, position).

and also how to receive in the actionResult a list/array of value pairs.

this is my PackerController:

```
    public ActionResult SetByCity(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var supplier = db.Suppliers.Where(s => s.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

        var mySupplierOrders = db.Orders.Where(o => o.SupplierId == supplier.Id && o.SupplierApproval == 1).Include(o => o.Clients).Include(o => o.Suppliers);
        return View(mySupplierOrders.OrderBy(o => o.Clients.BusinessAddress).ToList());           
    }
```

and this is the view for "SetByCity":

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.BusinessName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.BusinessAddress)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreateDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PayDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discount)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalPrice)
            </td>
            <td>
                <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("SetOrdersPosition", "Packer")" id="editform">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@item.Id">
                    <input type="number" name="Position" min="1" max="@Model.Count()">@*i need to put all the positions and id's of all the items in a pairs list and send it to the controller*@
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
<input type="submit" value="send" form="editform" />
```

and this is the receiving actionResult "SetOrdersPosition" in the PackerController:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SetOrdersPosition(List<id,position>)
    {
        //does something...
    }
```

i don't know what to put in the parameters that the SetOrdersPosition gets...

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using the Model name called "Suppliers".
So in get method pass that into view.
You needs to do come little changes accordingly to use Begin Form in your view, so that you can directly post your model data to controller.
Use this item inside body.
Don't forget to declare the model which you are using in the view page like below.
@model MVC.Models.Suppliers

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SetOrdersPosition", "Packer", FormMethod.Post))
    {
      <table>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
           {
     <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.BusinessName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Clients.BusinessAddress)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CreateDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PayDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Discount)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TotalPrice)
        </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td>
      </tr>
     }
     </table>
}
```

Controller Code [HttpPost]

```
 public ActionResult SetOrdersPosition(Suppliers _suppliers)
  {
    //does something...
  }
```

Comment: that is not what i need...
i am using the orders model not suppliers..
in the view i am showing to the user(supplier) his orders and i want him to set the order of the orders. for example order number(thats the id of ther order) 2 in the first place, order number 14 in the second place, etc.
and then the send button should be outside of the table and i need it to send to the controller the values of id(hidden) and position for each order.